# Group values using wildcards

Tags: sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database as follows:

```
Forename, Surname, District, Religion
John, Doe, Springfield, Cathlick
James, Smith, Springfield, RC
Bill, McGee, Springfield, Presbyterian
James, Campbell, Springfield, Presperterien
Michael Doyle, Washington, Roman Catholic
```

I wish to count the number of Catholics and Presbyterians in each District, as follows:

```
District, Catholic, Presbyterian
Springfield, 2, 2
Washington, 0, 1
```

Where I am using `%Cath%` and `RC` to match Catholic and `%Pres%` to match Presbyterian. There are a huge number of spelling errors with regard to religion. How would you recommend I group the various spelling variations for each religion in order to add up the number with each religion per district?

Comment: What language are you using the database from?

Comment: @Shawn I am using Sqlite3 for the database and programming in Python. I can solve the problem in Python but wondering if there is an sqlite approach.

Comment: If you can write a function in Python to transform random strings into a desired normalized one (using approximate string matching or something to figure out what it's supposed to be), you can register that as a user-defined sqlite function that can be used in sqlite queries.

Comment: Then you can do something like `SELECT District, count(CASE WHEN fix_religion(Religion) = 'Catholic' THEN 1 END) AS Catholic, ... FROM yourtable GROUP BY District;` (Or just clean up the data in one pass through the table, which will be more efficient in the long run; `UPDATE yourtable SET Religion = fix_religion(Religion);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TOTAL()` aggregate function which returns `0` instead of `null` with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT District, 
       TOTAL(Religion LIKE '%Cath%' OR Religion = 'RC') Catholic, 
       TOTAL(Religion LIKE '%Pres%') Presbyterian
FROM tablename
GROUP BY District;
```

If you identify other cases not covered by the current conditions, you can add them inside `TOTAL()` with the operator `OR`.

But, what you should do is update the table to the correct values:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Religion = CASE
  WHEN Religion LIKE '%Cath%' OR Religion = 'RC' THEN 'Catholic'
  WHEN Religion LIKE '%Pres%' THEN 'Presbyterian'
END
WHERE Religion NOT IN ('Catholic', 'Presbyterian');
```

Then your requirement is simpler:

```
SELECT District, 
       TOTAL(Religion = 'Catholic') Catholic, 
       TOTAL(Religion = 'Presbyterian') Presbyterian
FROM tablename
GROUP BY District;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=920ec0171ab2ed7150518829d10786d7).